# How to fill datagrid when complex join query is available?

Tags: c#

I have problem to fill grid in c#

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT data.acno, data.BillNo AS, data.Name,
Sum([Price]*[qty]) AS ટોટલ FROM data INNER JOIN agro ON data.BillNo = agro.BillNo 
GROUP BY data.acno, data.BillNo, data.Name, data.db, data.Date HAVING 
(((data.db)='true') AND ((data.Date) = '" + coGuj(drpDate.Text) + "'))", con);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);
viewgrid_credit.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

This code write to fill grid but no arise any error not fill grid only display heading of grid but not return require output.

Query is 100% correct this query run in access successfully and also return result.

Comment: Are you connecting to the right database?

Comment: You may also want to read about SQL injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Comment: @lc : yes right connection

Comment: @ Grant Winney : i put break point but at debug i am only watch heading

Answer (score 0):

1) Try debugging it and set a break-point at :

```
da.fill(ds)
```

to see if any data is returned.

2) If that does not work, I will suggest breaking the query down and using a few simple queries first.

```
    var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT data.acno, data.BillNo, data.Name,
                                Sum([Price]*[qty]) AS ટોટલ 
                                FROM data", con);

    var ds = new DataSet();
    var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    viewgrid_credit.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

See if this works and then append your extra query.

Comment: Simple query properly work but this query not give output, how can i do more any other way to execute query?

Answer (score 0):

There is only single mistake (but that not mistake becasue in access that is return result properly). When we fire query directly in access then '*' is allowed to pattern matching but in **C#** that compulsory to use '%' require.